# Libgdx: Pause between one cycle of animation

Tags: libgdx

I have animation with 5 frames. I want to make pause for x seconds every time one animation cycle ends

1,2,3,4,5 (pause) 1,2,3,4,5 (pause) ...

```
    Array<AtlasRegion> regions =  atlas.findRegions("coin");
    animGoldCoin = new Animation(1.0f / 20.0f, regions, PlayMode.LOOP);
```

I can't find way to do this.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't really like the animation class, you can make your own.

```
    float pauseTime=5f; // lets say that you want to pause your animation for x seconds after each cicle

float stateTime=0f; // this variable will keep the time, is our timer
float frameTime=1/20f; //amount of time from frame to frame
int frame=0; // your frame index
boolean waiting=false; // where this is true, you wait for that x seconds to pass

void Update()
{
    stateTime+=Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime();
    if(!waiting && stateTime>frameTime) // that frame time passed
    {
        stateTime=0f; // reset our 'timer'
        frame++; // increment the frame
    }
    if(waiting && stateTime>=0)
    {
        frame=0;
        waiting=false;
    }
    if(frame>=NUMBER_OF_FRAMES)
    {
        frame--;
        waiting=true;
        stateTime=-pauseTime;
    }
}


}
```

I think this will work, do you understand what I did?

Answer (score 0):

I just had a similar problem but managed to come up with a solution. It works well for me but may not be the best way to go about it.. I'm still learning.

I created a new animation from the old animation's frames but with a speed of 0. It stops on the frame its at until the player speed changes.

```
if(speedX == 0f && speedY == 0f){
            playerIdle = new Animation(0f,playerAnim.getKeyFrames());
            playerAnim = playerIdle;
        }
```

I know its an old question, but hopefully this will be useful to someone.

Answer (score 0):

I made a quick solution in my search to pause a Libgdx animation.
I wanted an animation to pause when I pressed the spacebar. 
I did try the above method of instantiating a new object and it did work. So I tried to just set the frame duration to 0, but that didn't work for some reason. This a less expensive method w/o instantiation.
If you want to pause an animation simply create three variables two are Boolean variables named toStop and hasLaunched another is a TextureRegion named launchFrame. Haslaunched is used to tell me when the spacebar is pressed.

```
if (InputHandler.hasLaunched && toStop ) {
        launchFrame = launchBarAnimation.getKeyFrame(runTime);
        toStop = false;
    } else if (InputHandler.hasLaunched && !toStop){
        batcher.draw(launchFrame, 90, 20, 50, 37);
    } else {
        batcher.draw(launchBarAnimation.getKeyFrame(runTime), 90, 20, 50, 37);
    }
```